# Implement a Job Scheduler using Dispatch Queues

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

Question: Implement a job scheduler which takes in function f and int n and calls f after n seconds.

Since im using Obj C to answer this question, I should probably use dispatch queues instead of selectors or function pointers.

Here's my attempt to implement the answer, but it's not returning a time stamp:

```
void jobSch(dispatch_queue_t queue, int64_t n, dispatch_block_t f)
{
    NSLog(@"%d\n", n);
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, n * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), f);
}

void (^aBlock)(void) = ^(){
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
        dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
            jobSch(queue, 3, aBlock);
        });
        dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Also my intended implementation would be able to call jobSch(queue, 10, aBlock) at runtime 0 and jobSch(queue, 3, aBlock) at runtime 2, so that would mean the second call would print before the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `main` is exiting long before your enqueued block is run. And that is because your call to `dispatch_group_wait` isn't waiting. And that is because your dispatch group is empty.

In order for a dispatch group and a call to `dispatch_group_wait` to be useful, you need to make paired calls to `dispatch_group_enter` and `dispatch_group_leave`.

You need to call `dispatch_group_enter` before you start any async call and you need to call `dispatch_group_leave` after the block has finished (`aBlock` in this case).

Your code is not setup to make this easy. You would need to make `group` a global variable. Then you can call `dispatch_group_enter` and `dispatch_group_leave` where needed.

Something like this should work:

```
dispatch_group_t group;

void jobSch(dispatch_queue_t queue, int64_t n, dispatch_block_t f)
{
    NSLog(@"%d\n", n);
    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, n * NSEC_PER_SEC), queue, f);
}

void (^aBlock)(void) = ^(){
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        group = dispatch_group_create();

        // no need for dispatch_group_async here
        jobSch(queue, 10, aBlock);
        jobSch(queue, 3, aBlock);

        dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also note that you never actually make use of `queue` inside `jobSch`.

You need to change:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, n * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), f);
```

to:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, n * NSEC_PER_SEC), queue, f);
```

Comment: So I tired running your solution, and it does hit the jobSch function, but it doesn't execute aBlock

Comment: See the end of my answer. You need to use `queue` instead of `dispatch_get_main_queue()`. This is because the call to `dispatch_group_wait` is already on the main queue. So any attempt to run any other code on the main queue will block forever.

Comment: That was it, I completely overlooked that, thank you!